# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, .so

Was trying to upload my android application built in Android Studio on playstore but i get that error. Searched everywhere tried all possible solutions suggested but no success.
My application uses 2 modules (main app module and a library module)

My module app gradle files:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk{ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'}
       /* testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"*/

    }
   /* packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libvudroid.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libvudroid.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libvudroid.so'
    }*/
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':scanlibrary')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:19.0.3'
    implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

THE COMMENTED CODE IS WHAT I TRIED BUT NO SUCCESS

module scanLibrary gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk{ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'}
         //   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        /*  ndk
                {
                    moduleName "Scanner"
                }
    */
    }
    sourceSets.main
            {
                jni.srcDirs = []
                jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Manually tried adding the "x86_64" and "arm64-v8a" directories but it says "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/xx-yyy==/lib/arm64/libopencv_java3.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit"

[Added folders - highlighted on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqIzT.png)

I suppose the solution could be finding 64 bit .so files for that module but i dont understand to find this. I'm a beginner in android studio
Its been 2 days trying to set this. Please help me thanks in advance
Screnshot-

Comment: Just for investigation: Unzip your apk and look for below folders and check where is the .SO file missing. And then you search for why that .SO is missing.

'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'

Comment: x86_64 and arm64-v8a  folders were not present. I added them manually

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the 3rd party OpenCV shared library - you've got to have a cross-compiled version for each different architecture.

There might be precompiled versions but I would get the source and use the proper toolchain from the NDK to build the library for each architecture. See [Using the NDK with other build systems](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems)